# What steps do I need to take to use the Ionic Framework with trigger.io?

Tags: html, mobile, cross-platform, trigger.io, ionic-framework

I unsuccessfully searched for some documentation of how to integrate the Ionic Framework with trigger.io, but I don't see any.

If anyone knows or has some, I'd love to see them. If not, I'll venture forward and post my steps here :)

Answer (score 2):

### Including Ionic Framework

Ionic Framework provides CSS and JavaScript libraries that you would include in your HTML. There are two methods for including Ionic Framework in your trigger.io app:

#### 1. Store the Files Locally (development/production):

- You can download the Ionic CSS and JavaScript files from the [Ionic CDN](http://code.ionicframework.com/#).
- Add the JS, CSS, and fonts folders to your src folder.
- Reference ionic.min.css and ionic.bundle.js in your `index.html` file like so:

```html
<link href="/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

- This is the same as including any other libraries in your HTML.
- Note that [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is included in `ionic.bundle.js`, so I would suggest checking out the AngularJS [API documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).

#### 2. Use a CDN (development only):

A [content delivery network (CDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) is a system of servers that delivers files to a client efficiently based on location.

You can include Ionic files in your project by linking them from the Ionic CDN:

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

While Ionic is still in the beta stages you should make sure to always change your CDN link or download the new files whenever they release a new version.

*I'd avoid using the CDN if possible, as it can cause problems if the phone loses internet connection. It also means that you are re-downloading the files every time the app runs.*

### Firebase

I'd also suggest checking out [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), a great backend solution for mobile apps. It can also handle user authentication.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```