# What are the Absolute Minimum Reqs to Use Ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I set up a starter app using [the phone gap app emulator](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/cli/). The app runs fine, I can edit things, etc. Now I want to use Ionic.

Their [starter page](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) has a bunch of... on it, and basically wants me to install their own starter project. If I understand correctly, most of what is installed is a bunch of bower packages, gulp, cordova itself - etc. IF I understand correctly, I don't need most of their "starter" stuff, even for a blank app.

So what DO I need as an absolute minimum to use ionic components? I am basically only interested in the dropdown navigation and reacting to native functionality (swiping screen, etc).

Edit: Heh, I don't mind the downvotes, but consider that the official [page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) does nothing to answer the question, whereas most things do, for example Ui Bootstrap will clearly tell you that all it needs is angular and its css, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimum Prerequisites for Ionic**

1.Basic `programming` / `JavaScript` knowledge

2.Familiarity with `AngularJS`

3.Install `Node.js`[You will need to install various packages for Node.js, we recommend that you [follow these installation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) instructions which use npm.]

4.Install the `Ionic CLI`

After follwing the above steps.You are able to create any type of 
applications.There are many posts and articles on the Ionic Framework but sometimes it is difficult to locate exactly what you need. This [website](http://mcgivery.com/100-ionic-framework-resources/) will help for doing any thing in ionic.

**Some ionic blogs**

1.[Blog 1](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/the-definitive-ionic-starter-guide)

2.[Blog 2](http://www.gajotres.net/)

3.[Blog 3](https://blog.nraboy.com/?s=ionic&submit=Search)

Comment: I actually found an answer, so my q should probably be marked as a dupe, but thank you. Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129089/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-use-the-ionic-framework-with-trigger-io

Comment: @VSO Glad to help you