# How do I access Ionic framework from Trigger.io?

Tags: ionic-framework, path, directory-structure, trigger.io

I want to use the Ionic UI framework with Trigger.io for my hybrid mobile app, but it isn't clear to me just how to combine the two in my code because it's not like using Jquery where you just add the library to a script tag. 
 After install, both of these frameworks provide their own "hello world" type of  index.html file, their own css and js files as well as framework specific configuration files which I know are important. So which  one do I use as a base and how do I call into the other framework from that base? How do I structure the project file tree to combine the two so that when I go to do an app build for distribution, there isn't some crazy error because the frameworks are set up to look for their own files via set paths?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one answer I found in my googling.

[What steps do I need to take to use the Ionic Framework with trigger.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129089/what-steps-do-i-need-to-take-to-use-the-ionic-framework-with-trigger-io)

here is an example project on git hub:

https://github.com/travisrussi/ionic-triggerio

here is the link to the ionic cdn to be used for testing:
https://code.ionicframework.com/#